# Error: Type of arg 1 to each must be hash (not hash element)

Tags: perl, hash, syntax

I'm getting this error when attempting to run this script - on this line

**Type of arg 1 to each must be hash (not hash element)**

```
    while (my ($action, $value) = each($cameras{$camera}{$mode})) {
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dereference the hash:

```
 while (my ($action, $value) = each(%{ $cameras{$camera}{$mode} })) {
```

Comment: Another, newer way to dereference in the postfix deref: `$cameras{$camera}{$mode}->%*` https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `$cameras{$camera}{$mode}` is a reference to a hash:

```
each ( %{ $cameras{$camera}{$mode} } );
```

As the error says, type of arg 1 to each must be a hash (not a hash ref).

If it is not a hash ref, then you cannot use `each` on it.